# Fresh install of Windows 10 cannot install feature updates, error 0xc1900101

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update

## Problem

I have not been able to install feature updates for some time on my machine.  It will install a feature update, then when it's done, the system will POST but the screen will be black and the fan will be running faster than normal.  It will stay that way until I reset the machine.  When I do that, Windows will try once to "recover," then it will roll back the update. It seems like the problem started with version 2004.

I'm currently running Win 10 Pro 1909.  I ignored this issue for awhile, assuming it would just resolve itself, but it hasn't, and now [version 1909 is no longer supported](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-these-versions-just-reached-end-of-service-no-more-security-patches-coming/).

## What I've tried so far

### Try 1 (Main hard disk, what's been happening for the past ~1 year)

Here's the update history from my main hard disk, which is currently running Win 10 Pro 1909 on an MBR disk that boots with the UEFI Compatibility Support Module enabled:

[image: main hard disk update failures]

Here's the SetupDiagResults.log from the most recent attempt:

```
Matching Profile found: FindRollbackFailure - 3A43C9B5-05B3-4F7C-A955-88F991BB5A48
SetupDiag version: 1.6.2107.27002
System Information:
    Machine Name = MYPC
    Manufacturer = To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Model = To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    HostOSArchitecture = 1033
    FirmwareType = PCAT
    BiosReleaseDate = 20190604000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = BIOS Date: 06/04/19 10:18:18 Ver: 05.0000E
    BiosVersion = L3.43
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.18363
    HostOSBuildString = 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.19041.1165 (vb_release_svc_prod1.210730-1848)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Professional
    RegisteredAV = Windows Defender
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 8/27/2021 1:18:09 PM
    UpgradeEndTime = 8/27/2021 2:12:07 PM
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 00:53:58
    CV = xYi3jS1fI0yohFsU
    ReportId = 7BEB55B6-2C37-4731-86AC-1A0B8260BE3C


Error: SetupDiag reports rollback failure found.
Last Phase = Post First Boot
Last Operation = Ensure suspended services are stopped
Error = 0xC1900101-0x40017
LogEntry: 

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Post First Boot
    Phase Started: 8/27/2021 2:11:18 PM
    Phase Ended: 8/27/2021 2:12:06 PM
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:48
    Completed Successfully? True


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: Ensure suspended services are stopped
    Operation Started: 8/27/2021 2:12:06 PM
    Operation Ended: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00.0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

## Try 2 (New blank hard disk with fresh install)

Some time ago I read that this problem may have had something to do with Compatibility Support Module, however it appears that UEFI cannot boot an MBR disk without that, so I recently got a fresh disk to use as an OS disk, disabled the CSM, and installed a fresh copy of Win 10 Pro on it (from my original 1903 media).  However, that's done nothing to fix the problem:

Here's the update history from the new (GPT) hard disk, with a fresh Windows install (zero customization), and the CSM disabled:

[image: new hard disk update failures]

What's interesting here is that both 2004 and 20H2 failed in the same way as I described above (black screen, several manual boots before automatic rollback), but 1909 failed with a different error code and rolled itself back without any manual intervention.  Also, I somehow managed to successfully install 1909 on my main HD at some point.

## Try 3 (install 21H1 on top of install from Try 2 using DVD)

I created an install DVD for 21H1 using the Windows Media Creation Tool, and installed it on top of the install from Try 2.  This ran into the same boot issue at first (black screen after POST, fans running fast), however, after rebooting, the automatic recovery routines actually managed to fix something, and 21H1 booted.

I then tried installing the updates pending for 21H1, and those immediately hosed everything worse than before.  Now the machine can't boot (black screen, fast fans), but instead of the updates getting rolled back, I get some kind of "recovery" UI that gives me an option to reboot, then more stuff (like uninstalling updates) under "advanced options."

## Question

I'm kind of at a loss of how to proceed at this point. The advice in the [Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-help-with-windows-10-upgrade-and-installation-errors-ea144c24-513d-a60e-40df-31ff78b3158a) for error 0xc1900101 is pretty generic, and I've already followed all the advice and even performed a fresh install.

Is there any way I can get more detailed debugging information than the error codes?  Like what the machine is trying to do when if freezes on boot after an update?

## System Info

OS: Windows 10 Pro
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700
Motherboard: ASRock X470 Taichi Ultimate
Graphics card: Radeon RX 570

[image: CPU Z CPU]

[image: CPU Z Mainboard]

[image: CPU Z Graphics]

[image: Windows Specifications]

[image: Graphics Driver]

## Update

While waiting for a new CPU from eBay so I could attempt to update my motherboard's BIOS*, my deferrals ran out and Windows Update forced me to run the 2004 update (on my "main" HD from Try #1).  This time it froze after the first boot, as always, but after resetting the machine the first time, **it actually managed to recover the installation**.  Previously it would always freeze again and had to reset once more, after which it would roll back to 1909.  Let's hope I don't run into worse problems, like I did in Try #3.

For the record:

* [I am unimpressed with AsRock's support](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X470%20Taichi%20Ultimate/index.asp#BIOS). They recommend Pinnacle Ridge CPUs use a BIOS older than my MB shipped with, and I need to send it in to them to downgrade if I don't want to risk bricking my MB doing a hack downgrade.  From a practical standpoint, that's so crazy it made more sense for me to upgrade my CPU.

I am also unimpressed with Windows and Microsoft.  This kind of inscrutable update behavior is totally unacceptable.  I'm glad it finally worked, but why the hell did it take 1+ years for an update *they were forcing on me* to successfully install?

Comment: Windows Features have worked for me since V10240.  I suggest not spending excessive time on this. Back up anything you need, format and then install V21H1 (now current).

Comment: Is there a special way that I should do that?  I already (essentially) did what you recommend.  New disk, installed Win 10 from the install media, and Windows Update *still failed* installing these updates.  It decided to start with 20H2, and then started attempting older versions.

Comment: You may wish to check in with the PC CPU Manufacturer (Support). All the machines we used at Customers (all Intel) all supported Windows Features.

Comment: Provide the log from SetupDiag.  I have solved what seemed impossible errors installing feature updates in the past.

Comment: Probably a driver error>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-help-with-windows-10-upgrade-and-installation-errors-ea144c24-513d-a60e-40df-31ff78b3158a

Comment: Do a [BIOS update](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/X470%20Taichi%20Ultimate/index.asp#BIOS) before continuing. Do you have the sub-code of your error 0xc1900101?

Comment: SetupDiag will determine if it’s a driver.  There is a way to determine which driver it is but only if it’s being called out by SetupDiag

Comment: @harrymc I am hesitant to do a BIOS update because I have a Pinnacle Ridge CPU and all the versions on the page higher than mine say "ASRock do NOT recommend updating this BIOS if Pinnacle, Raven or Summit Ridge CPU is being used on your system."  Also my BIOS L3.43 is not listed for download, so I couldn't go back if I had problems.

Comment: @Ramhound The SetupDiagResults.log says `Error = 0xC1900101-0x40017`.  I assume the second part is the subcode.  How do I interpret the SetupDiag results? I can post the log somewhere, but only after I've scrubbed it for anything that looks like personal info (looks like it's got my username in some places).

Comment: Yes, the output provides information.  Especially the stage of the upgrade.  The SetupDiag website also has information to decode the error message.

Comment: Provide the most recent **C\$WINDOWS ~BT \Sources\Panther\CompatData [date-time].xml** if you can

Comment: I assume you mean `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT`, and I don't have that directory.  I have a `C:\$WINDOWS.~WS`, though, but no `CompatData` there.

Comment: I didn’t blame you for anything. Your detecting an attitude that doesn’t actually exist. The reason the updates have failed are due to at this time an unidentified system configuration issue on your end. What I can do is help diagnose what that issue is exactly, that’s all I can do, provided you give me that chance.

Comment: Can you indicate if your HDD running Windows 1909 is currently GPT or MBR?

Comment: I can’t tell if you have figured out your issue and are now running 21H1 or if you are still having problems updating to 21H1. I also cannot tell if your disk is GPT or MBR. 19H2, 20H2, and 21H1 are all practically the same update.  I deleted the first part of this comment in its original iteration

Comment: @KayproII - Do you have Google Drive installed?

Comment: The issue was that I could not update from Windows 1909, and those updates failed in a the same inscrutable way several times.  My MBR drive updated to 2004 today, though the successful update process still shows some of the same symptoms the as failed updates (very similar to my update from 1903 to 21H1 on my GPT drive in Try 3).  I haven't figured anything out, and I am dreading a worse problem the next time Windows Update runs (like I experienced in Try 3).

Comment: I do not have Google Drive.  SetupDiag reports no problems (because the update finally installed).